# ¿Cómo quitar espacio superior en este RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout

No logro quitar el espacio en blanco que aparece en la parte superior de este RecyclerView. Quiero que aparezca inmediatamente después del Action Bar.

#### Layout del Fragmento

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.HomeFragment">
    
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### Layout para el RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0.5dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="0.5dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="0.1dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="82dp"
                android:maxHeight="82dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                card_view:tint="@color/color_mainrecycler_bg" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_Material"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="-50dp"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:textColor="@color/transparent"
                android:textSize="85dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_Elemento"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Material"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:textColor="@color/color_mainrecycler_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Si observan la captura, hay un espacio en blanco entre la AppBar y el Recyclerview que quisiera eliminar y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo. Agradezco cualquier ayuda, y si hace falta mostrar alguna parte de mi XML me avisan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, logro identificar que el paddingTop puede estar causando ese inconveniente, y de hecho la franja que quieres eliminar es parte del recyclerView. Trata de eliminar esa propiedad 
`android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`
Voy a suponer que el actionBar esta en el activity y el fragmento lo montas debajo del actionBar y por eso al darle ese padding te hace un espacio de tamaño similar que te queda en blanco.

Comment: @GustavoMora pues has dado en el clavo. He quitado `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` y se ha resuelto. Sugiero que lo pongas como respuesta por si puede servir a alguien más en un futuro. Gracias.